# Counter not incrementing

Tags: java, if-statement, counter, selection-sort

I have an assignment to count the assignments and comparisons in a selection sort.  For some reason my assignment counter isn't incrementing.  I've tried adding it above the swap and I've tried incorporating into the swap method - to no avail.  Any ideas why it's not working?

Update: The counter doesn't work for this

```
            Integer[] test = {1, 0, 4, 2};
            selectionSort(test);
```

But it does work for this:

```
    selectionSort(new Integer[] {1, 0, 4, 2});
```

Anyone know why?

```
public static void selectionSort(Integer[] array)
{
    int assignmentCounter = 0;
    int comparisonCounter = 0;
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        int minIndex = i;
        for(j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
        {
            comparisonCounter++;
            if(array[j].compareTo(array[minIndex]) < 0)
            {
                minIndex = j;
                assignmentCounter++;
                swap(array,minIndex,i);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Selection Sort Comparisons: " + comparisonCounter + "\nSelection Sort Assignments: " + assignmentCounter);
   for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[k] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n ");
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is your array sorted?

Comment: What is the value of assignmentCounter that you are getting now?

Comment: Did you try adding logging statement or stepping through in a debugger?

Comment: The test array I'm using is {1, 0, 4, 2}  The counter is staying at 0 the whole way.  I'm using eclipse - gonna try it in the terminal now.

Comment: This is nuts.  The array sorts, so the swap method is working, the counter just wont increment.

Comment: @MayNotBe What does your method print?

Comment: Didn't work in the terminal either.  @JamesKingsbery: I have to learn the debugger and google "logging statement". :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Selection Sort Comparisons: 6
Selection Sort Assignments: 0
0, 1, 2, 4,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    selectionSort(new Integer[] { 1, 0, 4, 2 });
}
```

I get the output

```
Selection Sort Comparisons: 6
Selection Sort Assignments: 2
0, 1, 2, 4,
```

Are you possibly expecting a `static` or other local variable also called `assignmentCounter` to be changed?

The variable `assignmentCounter` declared in `selectionSort` is local to that method. Nothing outside of it can see it.

Comment: Nope.  No other variable except the one local to that method.  My display is exactly yours except my second number is a 0.  So frustrating because I can't move on to actually do my assignment!!

Comment: @MayNotBe Try cleaning and recompiling your project. If it still doesn't work, I'd use a debugger.

Comment: Check this out: `Integer[] test = {1, 0, 4, 2};
  selectionSort(test);
  selectionSort(new Integer[] {1, 0, 4, 2});` my way doesn't increment, your way does.  Why do you think?

Comment: @MayNotBe Both of those are equivalent. They give me the same result, as expected.

Comment: Not in my program!!  Now I'm working on the big arrays, 1000 random numbers, and it's not showing any increments.  Seriously, wtf?

Comment: @may And use a debugger.